# How to write dynamic query columns into rows in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a question about in SQL Server: how to combine 4 columns into 1 column in a query.

Table: `emp`

```
empid | addr | sal | doj
------+------+-----+------------
  1   | hyd  | 10  | 10-01-1990
  2   | del  | 20  | 12-03-1999
  1   | pune | 50  | 12-03-2017
```

Based on above data I want output like below

```
empid | empvalues
------+---------------
1     | hyd
1     | 10
1     | 10-01-1990
2     | del
2     | 20
2     | 12-03-1999
1     | pune
1     | 50
1     | 12-03-2017
```

I tried with a query like this:

```
select 
    empid, cast (addr as varchar(100)) as empvalues 
from emp

union all

select empid, cast (sal as varchar(100)) as empvalues 
from emp

union all

select empid, cast (doj as varchar(100)) as empvalues 
from emp
```

This query is returning the correct result, but it takes a lot of time due to calling same table 3 times.

Can you please tell me how to write any alternative query to achieve this task in SQL Server?

Comment: Why would you *want* to do this? Keep your data normalised. Your columns will be different data types, and you can't store different data types in a single column (don't be tempted to use `sql_variant`). Also, your expected results don't even label the data, so is `'del'` the value of `addr`, `sal` or `doj`? You wouldn't know without consulting the original, normalise data. This is just a bad idea.

Comment: That isn't to say there aren't times when you do want to combine values of 2 columns into one; this is called "unpivoting". Just, this is **not** one of those times.

Comment: technically that is the way to do what you are trying to achieve. Not much optimization you can do with this.

Comment: I would suggest that there are *better* ways though, @Jeremy . The above requires 3 scans of the table, however, you could easily do it with 1, using `UNPIVOT` or a `VALUES` construct.

Comment: I can't help but think that the time here is spent casting data types to  varchar in order to stuff them into the same column. An UNPIVOT won't help with all that CPU overhead. This is a strange thing to do to your data though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using UNPIVOT, like this...

```
SELECT empid, empvalues
FROM (
    select empid, addr, convert(varchar(100), sal) as sal,  convert(varchar(100), doj, 103) as doj
    from emp
) pv
UNPIVOT
(
    empvalues
    FOR ev in (addr, sal, doj)
) AS ev
```

produces this output...

[image: sql results]

Resources for your reference...

https://codingsight.com/understanding-pivot-unpivot-and-reverse-pivot-statements/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Use **Cross Apply**:

```
create table emp (empid int, addr varchar(10), sal int, doj datetime) 

insert into emp (empid, addr, sal, doj)
values (1, 'hyd', '10', '10-01-1990'),
  (2, 'del', '20', '12-03-1999'),
  (1, 'pune', '50', '12-03-2017'); 


select empid,empvalues from emp
cross apply (values (cast (addr as varchar(10)))
,(cast (sal as varchar(10)))  
,(Format(doj,'MM-dd-yyyy')))   d(empvalues)
```

**Results:**

```
empid   empvalues
1   hyd
1   10
1   10-01-1990
2   del
2   20
2   12-03-1999
1   pune
1   50
1   12-03-2017
```

More info check below articles:

[docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
and 
[SQL Server CROSS APPLY and OUTER APPLY](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/)