# Columns into rows with identify in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a question about SQL Server: how to combine three columns into one column with identify in a query.

Table: emp

```
empid | addr1 | addr2 | addr3
------+-------+-------+------
  1   | hyd   | chen  | pune
  2   | del   | hyd   | nagp
  1   | pune  | bang  | keral
```

Based on above data I want output like below

```
empid | empaddrvalues | EmpFields | EmpFieldFlag
------+---------------+-----------+--------------
1     | hyd           | addr1     |   1
1     | chen          | addr2     |   2 
1     | pune          | addr3     |   3
2     | del           | addr1     |   1
2     | hyd           | addr2     |   2
2     | nagp          | addr3     |   3
1     | pune          | addr1     |   1
1     | bang          | addr2     |   2
1     | keral         | addr3     |   3
```

I tried with a query like this:

```
select 
    empid, 
    cast (addr1 as varchar(100)) as empaddrvalues, 
    'addr1' as EmpFields, '1' as  EmpFieldFlag 
from 
    emp
union all
select 
    empid, 
    cast (addr2 as varchar(100)) as empaddrvalues, 
    'addr2' as EmpFields, '2' as  EmpFieldFlag 
from  
    emp
union all
select 
    empid, 
    cast (addr3 as varchar(100)) as empaddrvalues, 
    'addr3' as EmpFields, '3' as EmpFieldFlag 
from 
    emp
```

This query is returning the correct result, but it takes a lot of time due to calling same table 3 times.

Can you please tell me how to write any alternative query to achieve this task in SQL Server?

Comment: Like I asked last time, why do you want to do this? You would be better off keeping your data normalised.

Comment: This looks very much like the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59566397/how-to-write-dynamic-query-columns-into-rows-in-sql-server#comment105300735_59566397) (but from a different account). What about those answers didn't you understand, and we can try to explain them to you.

Comment: Could well be, @MartinSmith . if that is the case though, I would suggest the OP doesn't understand the answer(s) they were previously given; which is actually the most importantly thing. If it is homework, then they aren't actually learning anything if they are asking how to make the change from how it was before to how they want it now. I feel that answering this would be doing them a disservice.

Comment: Great - another person that posts the same question independently to [multiple forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f34ffafe-729f-49a5-a6f0-3356b0262532/how-to-combine-3-columns-into-1-column-and-identify-in-sql-server?forum=transactsql).

Comment: That's the best way of getting people do work for your for free though, @SMor ;)

Comment: Do you mean the question I linked to, or the one on msdn, @MartinSmith ? I would suggest that the one on MSDN is definitely the same person, as even the wording with the question is identical. For the question i linked, I will admit I find it hard to believe it isn't the same person. The closing statement on  **both** is *"This query is returning the correct result, but it takes a lot of time due to calling same table 3 times.

Can you please tell me how to write any alternative query to achieve this task in SQL Server?"* That is far too much on a "coincidence".

Answer (score 1):

Unpivot by cross applying with 3 values (1, 2, 3) and CASE on that value to get the corresponding address.

```
create table dbo.employee
(
empid int,
addr1 varchar(50),
addr2 varchar(50),
addr3 varchar(50)
)
go

insert into dbo.employee(empid, addr1, addr2, addr3)
values
(1, 'hyd', 'chen', 'pune'),
(2, 'del', 'hyd', 'nagp'),
(1, 'pune', 'bang', 'keral');
go

select 
    e.empid, 
    case nums.n when 1 then addr1 when 2 then addr2 when 3 then addr3 end as empaddrvalues, 
    --concat('???', nums.n) as xyz,
    nums.n as EmpFieldFlag
from dbo.employee as e
cross apply (values(1), (2), (3)) as nums(n);

go

drop table dbo.employee
go
```